Unable to achieve the desired design in flutter
Question:
I am working on a Flutter project and aiming to replicate the design shown in the following image:

How can I achieve a similar layout and design in Flutter? Below is the code I have tried so far:
CODE I TRIED:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnboardingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ClipPath(
            clipper: InverseWaveClipper(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                  0.5, 
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "أهلاً",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "مرحباً بك في فيت بوكس",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "قبل أن نبدأ الرحله،",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "دعونا نتحدث",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "أدخل اسمك",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("التالي"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InverseWaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 60); 

    
    var controlPoint1 = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height - 100);
    var endPoint1 = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height - 60);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        controlPoint1.dx, controlPoint1.dy, endPoint1.dx, endPoint1.dy);

    var controlPoint2 = Offset(size.width * 3 / 4, size.height - 20);
    var endPoint2 = Offset(size.width, size.height - 60);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        controlPoint2.dx, controlPoint2.dy, endPoint2.dx, endPoint2.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

I'm stucked in this problem, Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


I have created a custom layout by trying below code
  body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(100))),
              height: 200,
              child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [Text("your text"), Text("your text")],
              )),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 81,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      height: 100,
                      width: 1),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 80,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(100))),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("your text"),
                    SizedBox(height: 100),
                    Text("your text")
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),

Change height, width and border radius as your requirement.

Yes it's same and worked thanks!

@MuhammadAli, If you found a solution from an answer, accept the answer so that others can easily find a solution to the same problem.

I implemented CustomClipper something like this some time ago but slightly different. I have implemented it in AppBar:
appBar: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(150),
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: CurveAppBar(),
    child: AppBar(
      title: const Text(
        'Some Text',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ),
),

CurvedAppBar:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CurveAppBar extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 50);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 5, size.height / 2.5, size.width / 2, size.height - 50);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 3 / 4, size.height, size.width, size.height - 50);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

It's slightly different from your design but you can adjust it. Hope it helps you.

Thanks for your time and repsonse, it is already solved!
